# Fixing Originating Point of a logarithmic spiral.

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

[Three spirals , Snapshot is taken from Desmos ,link is shared below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZhTZ.jpg)

Hello!
Consider these 3 spirals(Logarithmic spirals) defined by equation :

[r=aEXP(θ.b)]
b=cot(g.pi)

Limits of first Spiral(yellow/orage):
0  ≤  θ  ≤ 3.pi

Limits of second Spiral(red):
(2/3).pi  ≤ θ ≤  (5/3).pi + 2.pi

Limits of third Spiral(purple):
(4/3).pi  ≤ θ ≤  (7/3).pi + 2.pi

Each spiral is undergoing 1 and half rotations .i.e 3.pi rotations and they are all originating from points which are at an angle 120 degrees to each other.

Because of Limits originating point of first spiral(yellow/orange) is fixed and is defined by "a" .i.e. value of "a" defines starting  point of first spiral.
But the Originating points of 2nd and 3rd spiral are not fixed since thier minimum limit is not zero. If I change thier minimum to limti to "0" they lose the ability to be at an angle of 120 degrees to each other which is my question/problem.
---->I want to model all three spirals in such a way that thier Originating point stays fixed no matter what "b" is and I also want the Originating points to be at an angle of 120 degrees to each other.
1st spiral (yellow/orange ) does exactly that,but the other two red and purple dont.
I am attaching a picture and link of online Desmos File(which is an online graphing calculator) have a try at it if you feel like it.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bmtpirsmza

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).